# Computer Management "Services and Applications" always collapsed/closed

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-8

I often use the "Computer Management" in Windows and I always have to un-collapse (open) the "Services and Applications" prior to be able to see the Services.

This click is just absolutely not necessary - because the other two folders "System Tools" and "Storage" are already opened, but why not "Services and Applications" as well?

Does someone know how to have "Services and Applications" opened by default?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Locate `compmgmt.msc` in Windows\system32 or Windows\SysWOW64
2. Right-click and select `Author`
3. Expand `Services and Applications` and select `Services`
4. `File / Save As` and specify a different name but same location
5. Close `Computer Management` and click `Yes` if asked to save again
6. Open the newly saved version - it *should* open with `Services and Applications` expanded and `Services` selected (with `System Tools` and `Storage` expanded as before)

Comment: Nice, but when I rename my new compmgmtNEW.msc to the initial name compmgmt.msc it does not work anymore. Can I not override (or change) the existing compmgmt.msc ?

Comment: How did you overwrite compmgmt.msc with the edited version? Did you take ownership of it first? I'll see if the original can be overridden, but if not I guess you can always create a handy shortcut to the new one and use that instead.

Comment: Well I was able to override the original file (just get the ownership), but it does not work, somehow always the original app starts (without my configuration). Well I guess I need to use a new shortcut to the new compmgmt.msc.